# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database - nothing seems to work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database Error, when I try to migrate using php artisan migrate:install/ migrate. I have properly named database on my localhost SQL server. I'm using XAMPP to run it.

here's my .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=todo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

here's database.php:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

also here's create_todo_table.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTodoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('todo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('yettodo');
            $table->string('done');
            $table->string('user');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('todo');
    }
}
```

but constantly I keep getting this:

```
C:\Users\gracj\todo\todo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'todo'")
```

I am fully aware that there are plenty of threads like this on the Internet. The case is I feel like I've tried everything I could find (including installing different MySQL version - now I'm on 5.7, earlier I was on 8.0). I feel hopeless.

I had to change DB_PORT to 3307 since I had "3306 is occupied" error. I'm on Laravel 8 and PHP 8.0.2.

Please help!

Comment: Have you create the database named "todo" ?

Comment: it's not a connexion problem, you just dont have a database called "todo" as you defined it in your .env

Comment: "I have properly named database on my localhost SQL server." how are you verifying this?

Comment: "_I had to change DB_PORT to 3307 since I had "3306 is occupied" error_" This might mean there's another MySQL server running at port 3306. Did you create your database on the correct one, port 3307?!

Comment: "I have properly named database on my localhost SQL server." (sorry to quote the same thing) just to confirm, when you say SQL server you mean MySQL database server and not an MS SQL Server

Comment: That's it. I resolved this, you can check it down below (I posted a screenshot). Odd solution tough, if anyone knows why that happend, please comment on.

Comment: try to change 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed - very counterintuitive. Here's what I did.

I deleted and created todo database on my server couple of times, every time "php artisan config:clear" afterwards. I did try it earlier, BUT, I changed the DB_PORT in my .env file back to 3306 EVEN TOUGH XAMPP says it's busy, so in XAMPP I had to change it to 3307 (image below). As you can see, these aren't the same! Could you explain that? I'm worried since it might work just once and after few lines of code or migrations, it is possible for it to come back...

[image: Different PORTS]

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. However, mine was solved after creating a table on myphpAdmin.
Try:
open XAMP->click on admin in MySQL row and create database as stated in your DB_DATABASE=

try running php artisan migrate again.

Answer (score -1):

First set your Laravel .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todo
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=forge
```

if so then run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: it doesnt resolve the issue if he doesnt have a database named `laravel`. plus he can't use the 3306 port since he has multiple database servers running.